# TimerService#createTimer Ignores Delay

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I want to use the Java EE timer service to create a periodic task. Tutorials like [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/scheduling-in-java-enterprise-edition) suggest this is the way to go:

```java
@Startup
@Singleton
public class AutomaticBean {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        this.timerService.createTimer(0, 5000, null);
        System.out.println("AutomaticBean.initialize()");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void programmaticTimout(Timer timer) {
        System.out.println("AutomaticBean.programmaticTimout()");
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting to see is a message every 5 seconds. However it's send every one second.

```
11:20:13,341 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 6) AutomaticResendBean.programmaticTimout()
11:20:13,392 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 5) AutomaticResendBean.programmaticTimout()
11:20:14,340 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) AutomaticResendBean.programmaticTimout()
```

I have no idea why that won't work. I tried other methods of the timer service as well. `createSingleActionTimer` did not work either, and it created a periodic timer as well (instead of one that is executed a single time).

What is the problem? The container is Wildfly 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem had nothing to do with the actual setup, but someone else might have the same problem so here it goes:

On default JMS timers are created with a `TimerConfig` that is persistent. Which means once you create a timer that runs every second, this timer gets run even if you restart the server (or remove the creation of it).

So that's what happend. I had created a timer every second. Which ran every second. Then I created a second timer with a delay. Since the same code was run for both, I couldn't see that I had actually two timers.